# PHP CURL Assíncrono

Tags: php, slimframework

Tenho um arquivo PHP que faz um requisição POST via curl para outro arquivo PHP, preciso colocar essa requisição dentro de um loop e fazer umas 10 requisição de uma vez sem me preocupar com o retorno, existe um forma de fazer essa requisição sem ter que esperar a resposta para realizar a próxima chamada?

Ex: `

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) {
    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "/api/atualizar/$i");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

    // JSON de retorno 
    $jsonRetorno = trim(curl_exec($ch));
    $resposta = json_decode($jsonRetorno);
    $code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

    $err = curl_errno($ch);

    curl_close($ch);

    echo "Item $i enviado!";
}
```

?>`

Comment: por favor veja aqui [Como criar um exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Você precisa fazer isso com PHP? Digamos que essa linguagem não tão boa para trabalhar com assincronismo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Voce é capaz de fazer essa consulta usando as funções [curl_multi_init](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-init.php) e [curl_multi_add_handle](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-add-handle.php). Imagine que você tenha uma função que cria um request, retornando o curl handler, como abaixo:

```
function create_request($i) {
    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "/api/atualizar/$i");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

    return $ch;
 }
```

Usando as funções [curl_multi_init](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-init.php) e [curl_multi_add_handle](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-add-handle.php) você pode cria uma sessão e enfileira as requisições, sem esperar o retorno. Algo do tipo:

```
$session = curl_multi_init();

for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
    $ch = create_request($i);
    curl_multi_add_handle($ch, $session);
}
```

Depois, com a função do [curl_multi_exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-exec.php) você executa as chamadas enfileiradas.

```
do {
    $mrc = curl_multi_exec($session, $active);
} while ($mrc == CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM);
```

Voce pode remover esse do/while caso não queira esperar a resposta (apenas tem q chamar o curl_multi_exec 1x).

Comment: Perfeito exatamente como eu esperava. Obrigado